# difference between array and plain pointer with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

There is:

```
std::unique_ptr< double> d( new double[3] );
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr< double[]> darr( new double[3] );
```

At least one of the difference between the two seem to be that the later calls `delete[]` but both are valid..but how come? I mean how is memory deleted in first case, isn't that undefined behavior deleting array with `delete`?

Secondly I know `darr` above has `[]` operator defined but how to access 2nd and 3rd member of `d` since there is no `[]` operator defined.

Why would anyone use the first syntax rather than the 2nd?

Comment: The first one isn't valid.

Comment: Wow my question came from reading Dr Dobbs article  http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708 that's confusing than!

Comment: I've looked at the article but can't find any use of new int[x] but there is new int(x) which is the initializer value.

Comment: @Surt You are right, I got confused by the first code line there..my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
template <
    class T,
    class Deleter
> class unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>;
```

> Manages the lifetime of a dynamically-allocated array of objects (e.g. allocated with new[]).

Unfortunately, expression `std::unique_ptr<double>(new double[3])` compiles with no warnings or errors, ends up disposing the `new[]` allocation with `delete` (scalar version) which causes undefined behaviour at run-time.

You can use `std::vector<double>(3)` to have the array automatically allocated and disposed.

Answer (score 1):

> At least one of the difference between the two seem to be that the later calls delete[] but both are valid..

The first one is NOT valid.  The memory MUST be allocated with `new`, not with `new[]`.  The only reason it compiles at all is because the first syntax expects a `double*` as input and a `double[]` degrades into a `double*`.

> I mean how is memory deleted in first case

Using `delete`, not `delete[]`.

> isn't that undefined behavior deleting array with delete?

Yes.

> Secondly I know darr above has [] operator defined but how to access 2nd and 3rd member of d since there is no [] operator defined.

You have to use its `get()` method to access the underlying pointer, eg:

```
double value = d.get()[1]
```

> Why would anyone use the first syntax rather than the 2nd?

Noone should be being the first syntax for arrays.  The second syntax was specifically added for arrays.